# How to access resources from the server

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, asp.net-core-5.0, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have published an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API on Windows Server 2019 with IIS and I can't get access to my generated QRs, out of the server you can access with `www.page.com/api/files/QRs.png` but I need to make a report rdlc with that image but in the source of the image I have set `http://www.page.com/api/files/QRs.png` and it doesn't work.

If I use `http://localhost/api/files/QRs.png` in the source of the image report it works. Previously I had published this API to Azure with `www.azurepage.com/api/files/QRs.png` in the report and it worked, so I suppose that I have to configure something in IIS

Comment: In order to get help can you put your code and the error you are getting.

Comment: When you observed errors in the report, I believe IIS log files should record useful error codes to guide you through. So, don't jump too far and forget to take a look at the basics, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code

Comment: Besides, how you make a report rdlc with that image and which error codes is you received from the server is the question.